# error: unable to recognize "apps.yml": no matches for /, Kind=Template

Tags: templates, kubernetes, openshift

I'm struggling to apply this yaml below on openshift and I receive error "**error: unable to recognize "apps.yml": no matches for /, Kind=Template**", this is because of the version of the kubernetes?

**version of kubernetes and openshift:**

```
oc v1.4.1+3f9807a
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://xxxxxxx:6443
kubernetes v1.19.0+4c3480d
```

code:

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: Template
    metadata:
      name: app
      annotations:
        description: "App"
    objects:
      - apiVersion: v1
        kind: DeploymentConfig
        metadata:
          name: tao-app-deployment
          labels:
            version: appV1
            app: app
        spec:
          replicas: 1
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              version: appV1
              app: tao-app
          updateStrategy:
            type: RollingUpdate
            strategy:
              type: RollingUpdate
              rollingUpdate:
                maxSurge: 1
                maxUnavailable: 0
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                version: tao-appV1
                app: app
            spec:
              containers:
                - name: App
                  image: registry.gitlab.tech.domain/path/path_img/app:latest
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  ports:
                    - containerPort: 9000
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation issue however there is also an error no **Kind** of match

Which mean it's an issue of an API version

you can check the cluster supported API versions using

```
kubectl api-versions
```

you might try with changing the API version for template

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: app
  annotations:
    description: "App"
objects:
```

"- apiVersion: v1"
to
"- apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1"

Answer (score 0):

There should not be indentation after the line apiVersion.

Should be like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: app
  annotations:
    description: "App"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by upgrading my Openshift Client from 1.4 to 4.7

Regards